# Connection strings for MySQL and SQLite with ADO.NET

Tags: mysql, sqlite, connection-string

I would like to use F# to connect to databases other than SQL Server using the same code as in : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361033(v=vs.110).aspx

I assume I need the ADO.Net connector for the database (MySQL or SQLite etc.). However, once that is done, how should I modify the connection string in :

```
type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<"Data Source=MYSERVER\INSTANCE;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;">
let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext()
```

To indicate I want to use MySQL or SQLite etc.

Many thanks

Comment: Basically, any of the first 100 results from searching for "mysql connection string".

Comment: The queries that I had used didn't provide me wth those results, and the page I had initially landed on on the website mentioned below was not useful. My mistake ! Regardless, thank you for taking the time to read the question. And many thanks again to Adriano for his answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Connection string you're using is for Microsoft SQL Server.

MySQL connection strings: http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql
SQLite connection strings: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite

(from that links you can navigate to the proper connector you're using)